# android unit testing ui recorder a'la VS2010

Tags: android, junit, automation

I wonder, is there a UI recorder out there to automate unit test creation for android projects. I know the android SDK includes JUNIT support. I'm looking for tools that automate the process of creating test scripts. VS2010 has a built in recorder for instance that allows the automation of gui testing by recording the use of the application. This can then be saved as a test script and rerun after any changes are made to the application. So is there something similar for android using JUNIT or s similar testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

Bitbar has developed a tool for that, it's on Alpha now so anyone can test it for free. You can record the test on a real device and it will output Robotium tests from it.

[bitbar.com](http://bitbar.com/download)

Comment: This sounds interesting. I'll check that out, thanks for the info